# One question on Natale's work [Semisolvability of semisimple Hopf algebras of low dimension ]

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras

I am reading Natale's book [S. Natale, Semisolvability of semisimple Hopf algebras of low dimension, Mem. Amer. Math. Soc. 186 (2007), 123 pp.]. I can not understand a sentence "But this is not possible since ${\rm dim}A^{co q} = 9$....."  from the proof of Theorem 12.2.1. In my option, there are severa possible values of ${\rm dim}A^{co q}$ since we do not know the exact order of $\eta$, and the sentence above holds true if and only if  $|\eta|=2$. Who can explain it for me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can write to Sonia.

Answer (score 1):

One has that $dim(A)=dim\;(A^{co\; q})dim\;q(A)$. The claim is that $dim\;q(A)=2$, I don't know if $q$ restricted to $A$ is surjective.

Comment: It's the transpose of an inclusion, so of course it must be surjective!